# reading array of params in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrequest

If I have URL something like below:

```
http://test.com?x=1&x=2&x=3&x=4&x=5&x=6&x=7
```

Then how can I read all "x" values?

**Added new comment: Thanks for all your answers. I am basically from Java and .Net background and recently started looking Ruby and Rails. Like in Java, don't we have something similar as request.getParameterValues("x");**

Comment: Shouldn't your url be `http://test.com?x=1,2,3,4,5,6,7` instead, or something similar?

Comment: is this a rails http request and you want to parse x in your action or you have an url as string and want to parse it?

Comment: No, rails doesn't have the request.getParameterValues("x") functionality. Like PHP, it needs the query parameters to be specified with the "[]" suffix if there are to be multiple values for them. Honestly, I've always found this to be annoying, since it means you can't just replace a back end written using Servlets with one written using Rails without (if you use the multiple valued params pattern) changes to the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF IT IS A STRING, but not a http request**

Do this:

```
url = 'http://test.com?x=1&x=2&x=3&x=4&x=5&x=6&x=7'

p url.split(/(?:\A.*?|&)x=/).drop(1)
```

If you want to convert them to integers, do:

```
p url.split(/(?:\A.*?|&)x=/).drop(1).map(&:to_i)  (ruby 1.9)
```

or

```
p url.split(/(?:\A.*?|&)x=/).drop(1).map{|v| v.to_i}
```

Answer (score 26):

You should use following url instead of yours:

```
http://test.com?x[]=1&x[]=2
```

and then you'll get these params as array:

```
p params[:x] # => ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: agreed. That make sense in context of rails

Comment: I found that Rails 4.2.5 understands the serialization of brackets so params[:x] still worked even though my square brackets were being serialized in the URL. I am using AngularJS which was converting x[] into x%5B%5D.

Answer (score 2):

**IF IT IS A STRING, but not a http request** I even didn't imagine if author don't know how to handle params of request url...

```
url = "http://test.com?x=1&x=2&x=3&x=4&x=5&x=6&x=7"
vars = url.scan(/[^?](x)=([^&]*)/)
#=> [["x", "2"], ["x", "3"], ["x", "4"], ["x", "5"], ["x", "6"], ["x", "7"]] 
x = vars.map{|a| a[1]}
#=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
x.map!(&:to_i)
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or if you need to extract valuse only:

```
vars = url.scan(/[^?]x=([^&]*)/).flatten
#=> ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
vars = url.scan(/[^?]x=([^&]*)/).flatten.map(&:to_i)
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks for editing mine. Someone seem to be downvoting us. If the question did not mean string, then the question was ambiguous. We shouldn't be downvoted because of that.

Comment: It was accidently :) And I totally agree :) +1

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I am basically from Java and .Net background and recently started looking Ruby and Rails. Like in Java, don't we have something similar as request.getParameterValues("x");